# Twitter Steam analysis issue

Tags: python, file, twitter

I am trying to take a twitter stream, save it to a file and then analyze the contents. However I am having an issue with files generated in the program as opposed to create by CLI

Twitter Analysis program:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data = []

tweets_file = open(“test.txt”, “r”)

for line in tweets_file:
    try: 
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)

    except:
        continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets[‘text’] = map(lambda tweet: tweet[‘text’], tweets_data)
```

However with the last line I keep getting  “KeyError: ‘text’ “ which I understand to be related to the fact it can’t find the key.

When I first run the twitter search program, if I output the results to a file from the CLI, it works fine with no issues. If I save the output to a file from inside the program, it gives me the error?

Twitter Search program:

```
class Output(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        with open(“test.txt”, “a”) as tf:
            tf.write(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


L = Output()
auth = OAuthHandler(consKey, consSecret)
auth.set_access_token(Tok1, Tok2)

stream = Stream(auth, L)
stream.filter(track=[´cyber´])
```

If I run the above as is, analyzing the test.txt will give me the error. But if I remove the line and instead run the program as:

> python TwitterSearch.py > test.txt

then it will work with no problem when running text.txt through the analysis program

I have tried changing the file handling from append to write which was of no help.

I also added the line:

```
print tweet[‘text’]
tweets[‘text’] = map(lambda tweet: tweet[‘text’], tweets_data)
```

This worked and showing that the program can see a value for the text key. I also compared the output file from the program and the CLI and could not see any difference. Please help me to understand and resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide samples of each version of `test.txt`? My thought is that the JSON object indeed does not have a `text` attribute. When you use `> test.txt`, I don't see any printing in your script, so are you sure the result file isn't empty, therefore no iteration and no opportunity for key lookup failure since it never tries to do so?

Comment: Could you try a small file with one or two lines and each line is definitely a string formated of tweet. Becuase I am wondering there may exist some lines which are not tweets.

Comment: This following link is the result from CLI  https://pastebin.com/UPsH15BC

Comment: This is from the program itself: https://pastebin.com/Z1PXKKBY